# Programmatically changing azure management cert for multiple (600+) subscriptions

Tags: azure, certificate, instance

Our service has 600+ subscriptions, and they all share the same management cert.

Due to security reason, we would like to change management cert on the subscriptions periodically, but I have not yet found a way to do so programmatically.

I have found the "Add Service Certificate" cmdlet but it only allows you to upload the "Service certificate per service", and I need to be able to change "Management cert" for all 600+ subscriptions.

Could you please tell me if there is a programmatic way to do so?

Comment: Can't you create your own cmdlet to call the Add Service Certificate cmdlet 600 ways?

Comment: Service certificate can be added that way, but management cert should be added "per instance" and there is no way to do so using Add Service Certificate.

Comment: the API actually exposes a way to add Management Certificate (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj154124.aspx). So you just need to come up with a code that does that. In sharp it is fairly easy to come up with a code to do this. You may also want to take a look at: http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries